# C# : extract/retrieve child node from JSON structure

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How can we extract or retrieve child nodes values from JSON structure in C#.

my app is using [OpenWeatherMap](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=London,UK&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=1), I need to retrieve **name** from ***city***, **temp** from ***list*** and **description** from ***weather*** nodes, my JSON and Class structure are below

```
{
  "cod": "200",
  "message": 0.0284,
  "city": {
    "id": 2643743,
    "name": "London",
    "coord": {
      "lon": -0.12574,
      "lat": 51.50853
    },
    "country": "GB",
    "population": 0,
    "sys": {
      "population": 0
     }
  },
  "cnt": 1,
  "list": [
    {
      "dt": 1429268400,
      "temp": {
        "day": 12.21,
        "min": 4.86,
        "max": 13.18,
        "night": 4.86,
        "eve": 11.76,
        "morn": 12.21
      },
      "pressure": 1028.8,
      "humidity": 66,
      "weather": [
         {
           "id": 803,
           "main": "Clouds",
           "description": "broken clouds",
           "icon": "04d"
        }
      ],
      "speed": 5.9,
      "deg": 67,
      "clouds": 80
    }
  ]
}
```

**C# Class**

```
public class WeatherForeCast
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public decimal Day { get; set; }
    public decimal Min { get; set; }
    public decimal Max { get; set; }
    public decimal Night { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Till date I'm familiar with using JSON.net for serialize and deserialize C# objects to JSON which has exact same structure.

Comment: You need to create a class that has the same structure as your JSON object. The property names don't have to match exactly (e.g. capital first letter, etc.) You can use the JsonProperty[] attribute on each property to set the name. Once you've done this, you can use the JsonSerializer to read your JSON into a C# object. If you need a simpler WeatherForecast object in your app, you can map the returned JSON C# object to your WeatherForecast object.

Comment: You can do this without a class, too. E.g.: `dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStr);
double msgDbl = (double)jsonObj.message;`

Comment: @Mangist I don't want to create all the classes in my project which matches same structure as my JSON, I just want few property values from JSON structure and populate **WeatherForecast** object.

Comment: @BeingDev You don't need all the properties in your WeatherForecast object, but the ones you want from the JSON object must be in the same path/structure so the serializer can parse them.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you just want to populate an instance of `WeatherForecast`, you could use a few `SelectToken` calls on a plain `JObject`:

```
var parsed = JObject.Parse(json);
var forecast = new WeatherForeCast();

forecast.City = parsed.SelectToken("city.name").Value<string>();
forecast.Day = parsed.SelectToken("list[0].temp.day").Value<decimal>();
forecast.Description = parsed.SelectToken("list[0].weather[0].description").Value<string>();
forecast.Min = parsed.SelectToken("list[0].temp.min").Value<decimal>();
forecast.Max = parsed.SelectToken("list[0].temp.max").Value<decimal>();
forecast.Night = parsed.SelectToken("list[0].temp.night").Value<decimal>();
```

Note that this is pretty brittle though, it's making assumptions about the contents of the JSON. If the JSON changes, the path to various properties in `SelectToken` will be incorrect and this code will throw an exception.

Answer (score 4):

Use json2csharp.com to generate your classes.

```
public class Coord
{
    public double lon { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    public int population { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int population { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
}

public class Temp
{
    public double day { get; set; }
    public double min { get; set; }
    public double max { get; set; }
    public double night { get; set; }
    public double eve { get; set; }
    public double morn { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class List
{
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public Temp temp { get; set; }
    public double pressure { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
    public double speed { get; set; }
    public int deg { get; set; }
    public int clouds { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string cod { get; set; }
    public double message { get; set; }
    public City city { get; set; }
    public int cnt { get; set; }
    public List<List> list { get; set; }
}
```

Then use JSON.NET to deserialize into the class structure and extract the properties you want.

```
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

You now have an instance of RootObject and you can traverse it as needed to extract the specific value(s) you need.

Comment: Thank you Craig, but I just want to maintain **WeatherForecast** class in my app, I don't want to create all the classes u have listed.

Comment: Then you'll need to deserialize into a dynamic using `JObject.Parse` and then using "magic strings" to access the properties you need. However, IMO that's going to be more work and more fragile than simply copy-and-pasting the generated classes into your application and then using strongly-typed properties. I think you're making the wrong choice, but it's your application.

Comment: Thanks Craig, till now I don't know how to use `JObject.Parse`, I got the solution.