# Add child parameter in json

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have for example like this json:

```
{
  "parameter": "value",
  "parameter1" : {
    "childParameter": "value",
    "childParameter1": "value"
  }
}
```

Code example:

```
 RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
 request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
 request.AddParameter("parameter", "value");
 request.AddParameter("parameter1", ???);
```

I have to use RestSharp lib. How can i create this request with child node.
Can I do it without AddJsonBody.
Thanks.

Comment: You have to explain a bit more... what request? what child node?

Comment: i think bellow link can help you [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702616/c-sharp-extract-retrieve-child-node-from-json-structure)

Answer (score 0):

According to other posts on StackOverflow. Easiest would be to create your own POST body.

```
request.AddParameter("text/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Where `body` will be your complete json object